# Wifi doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I have a dual boot laptop(NP540U3C) with windows 8 and ubuntu. The issue is that every time I restart my computer I'd have to restart my router in order to connect to the internet. This does not happen with my other devices, or windows system. Please help me...

Here's the the result when I ran ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:b7:c3:0a:d3:ae  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:329101 (329.1 KB)  TX bytes:329101 (329.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:f7:33:9c:66:70  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::caf7:33ff:fe9c:6670/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:101717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:122719994 (122.7 MB)  TX bytes:7840981 (7.8 MB)
```

I tried the following

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down;
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

But it still doesn't work =/

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo ifdown wlan0` and `sudo ifup wlan0` where wlan0 is your NIC (wifi card name). If you do not know what it is use `ifconfig` or `ip a` to find the name. If this worked, add it into your `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` right before the last line that says "exit 0". What this does is every time you boot up, it will reset the wlan0 card. Hopefully this solution is for you!

Comment: Hi, I ran ifconfig, but I can not figure out what my wifi card name is, here's the result when I ran it.wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:f7:33:9c:66:70  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::caf7:33ff:fe9c:6670/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:101717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:122719994 (122.7 MB)  TX bytes:7840981 (7.8 MB)

Comment: @user2580016 Please add that information to your question!

Comment: Your wifi card is `wlan0`